# How to see list of authorized users google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet that I've authorized a few users to access.  Now I want to poll these people regarding a change.  How can I obtain a list of those people (e-mail addresses) that have been given access?

Since I'm here, how can I determine what access each has?

Thanks

Comment: Did my answer show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you have issues for my answer yet, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about your current situation? I would like to study to solve your issues.

Answer (score 1):

- You want to retrieve the editors and viewers list of a Google Spreadsheet.

I think that in order to achieve your goal, it is required to be used a script. In this answer, I would like to propose the method for achieving your goal using Google Apps Script.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Apps script. And run the function of `myFunction`. When the authorization screen is shown, please authorize the scopes. By this, the script is run.

```
function myFunction() {
  var spreadsheetId = "###";  // Please set the Spreadsheet ID.
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId);  // or SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var res = {
    owner: ss.getOwner().getEmail(),
    editors: ss.getEditors().map(e => e.getEmail()),
    viewers: ss.getViewers().map(e => e.getEmail()),
  };
  console.log(res)
}
```

- If you use the container-bound script of Spreadsheet, you can use `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()` instead of `SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId)`.

#### Result:

When above script is run, the following result is returned.

```
{
  "owner": "### your email address ###",
  "editors": [
    "### your email address ###",
    "### user's email ###",
    "### user's email ###",
  ],
  "viewers": [
    "### your email address ###",
    "### user's email ###",
    "### user's email ###",
  ]
}
```

#### References:

- [getOwner()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getowner)
- [getEditors()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#geteditors)
- [getViewers()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getviewers)

Comment: Thank you for answering my  question.  I'd been taken in a different direction and forgot about this question, actually.  My purpose was to be able to know who was the owner of certain rows (creator or last modifier of that row).  I'm sorry I didn't make it clearer.

Comment: Actually, the stated question was a problem for me too at one point.  But answer the second question overrode would solve it and some other issues I had.  I will test your solution and reply back within a day.

Comment: @Dennis Thank you for replying. I would like to wait for it.